# UITextField text content shifting right when becomes first responder

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

This is a part of a separate project. Basically, I am using a simple `UITextField` and making it look like a passcode digit field. 
So, the height is supposed to be bigger than the width(as per requested designs). Also, the entered character should be centered when typed. Currently, there is no logic. I was just trying out and when I enter a character, it shifts towards the right.

The character needs to be in the center (as it is similar to the passcode like UI's).

Using Xcode 9.3.

Here are the screenshots:
[image: default state]

[image: when the textfield made first responder]

[image: when a character is typed]

I have pushed the project on bitbucket. Feel free to clone and try it out. 
[Project Link](https://bitbucket.org/prat14k/controls_demo/src/master/)

Comment: If you need to center align text in a text field, then you just set the `textAlignment` property of that text field to `.center`.

Comment: check your constraints of textfield

Comment: @RakeshaShastri the textAlignment is been set for the textfield in the storyboard itself. Are you saying that everytime the user types, I have to set this property ?

Comment: @prat14k no. Can you show a gif of what is happening?

Comment: @RamprasathSelvam There isn't any code. Everything is in the Main.storyboard file which wont make sense if i just copy pasted it in here(it isn't that much readable). Thats why I have pushed the project and provided the link.

Comment: @Anbu.karthik yes I have checked. Its is having constraints for height, aspect Ratio, horizontally centered and top spacing to safe area. I know that the height and aspect Ratio contraint wont be needed as text field resizes itself as per the content, but i have mentioned it is a design requirement.

Comment: @RakeshaShastri  I have updated the question with the screenshots.